# Sketching graph of $\log(x) +2$

Tags: logarithms

Sketch the graph of $$\log(x)+2$$

The +2 tells me that it must 'shift up by 2' . However this is a logarithm graph and the asymptote is a vertical line . This means that it has no effect (no shift) .

How do I find the x intercept ?

A normal $y=\log(x)$ graph cuts the $x$ axis at 1 because $x= 10^y$ and I just sub $y=0 $ and it will give us $1$ .

But this graph has $+2$ how do I change the function into an exponential function ?

Answer (score 1):

To find $x$ intercept, $y = 0$. That means $\log(x)=-2$ or $x=e^{-2}$ if base is $e$.

If the base is $10$ then it will be $10^{-2}$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the graph of $\log(x)+2$. (in base $e$)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2 = \log e^2$, now use the rule for a sum of logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}
y&=\log_{10}(x)+2
&\text{This is the equation we're given.}
\\
y&=0
&\text{The $x$-intercept is when $y=0$.}
\\
0&=\log_{10}(x)+2
&\text{Substitute $y=0$ into line-$1$.}
\\
-2&=\log_{10}(x)+0
&\text{Subtract $2$ from both sides.}
\\
10^{-2}&=x
&\text{Invert the logarithm.}
\end{aligned}$$

If instead you mean $\log_e(x)$, just replace the $10^{(\cdot)}$ with $e^{(\cdot)}$.